# Why is this Kotlin class property not public?

Tags: java, kotlin, access-modifiers

I've got an app that is regularly using classes written in Kotlin which are accessed by other classes and their methods written in Java.

I had the following class in Java:

```
public class MyDataClass {
    public String color;
    public String action;
}
```

I've decided to move it to Kotlin:

```
class MyDataClass {
    var color: String = ""
    var action: String = ""
}
```

Upon recompiling, I'm now getting the following error message:

> /myPath/MyApp.java:[93,20] color has private access in myapp.command.MyDataClass

I get a similar error for `action`.

Per the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html), the default visibility modifier for class and properties (and a bunch of other things) is `public`.

Why are these properties being treated as `private`?

Comment: Because it's a private field with a public getter and a public setter. You cannot access fields directly in Kotlin, everything is properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's a private field with a public getter and a public setter. You cannot access fields directly in Kotlin, everything is properties.

Refer to: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "everything is properties"?

Comment: If you declare the `var something: String`, then it will always be "private field + public accessors". In Java, people typically called these "properties", or at least that's how I remember.

Comment: Good answer; minor addition: you can mark a property as `@JvmField` to have it compile to a field.

Comment: Ah yes, that is true. I'm not sure why I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you very much for your comment , adding JvmField annotaion solve problem that cause headache for me